# Actxserver function in matlab

Tags: matlab

I am going to make communication between Matlab and another software(DSATools).

A .bin file has been produced as an output by that software and I need to read it dynamically. As it is mentioned in the manuals of DSATools I should start with some thing like this to start the reading:

```
r = actxserver('ResultScript.BinReader')
```

But when I try it in command windows the following error will be appeared:

Error using `feval`

```
Server Creation Failed: Class not registered
```

Error in `actxserver` (line 86)

```
h = feval(['COM.' convertedProgID], 'server', machinename, interface);
```

Does anybody have any idea about these errors? What is the solution?
(My OS is Windows 8 64 bit. My matlab is 2013 64bit and DSATools can be used by both 64 and 32 bit OS.)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I've improved some of the formatting in your question so it has some syntax highlighting, but I'd recommend adding a more descriptive title that explains the issue you are facing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to install MATLAB 32-bit version. See this link:

http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/95116-why-am-i-not-able-to-use-32-bit-dll-com-objects-in-64-bit-matlab-7-3-r2006b

Comment: Guys, Many Thanks for trying to help me. Actually, I find the solution as user4732073 mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this using a registry trick [published here](https://techtalk.gfi.com/32bit-object-64bit-environment/). It also registers the COM object in the 64 bit registry list.

1. Locate your COM object GUID under the `HKey_Classes_Root\Wow6432Node\CLSID\[GUID]`
2. Once located add a new REG_SZ (string) value. Name should be AppID and data should be the same COM object GUID you have just searched for.
3. Add a new key under `HKey_Classes_Root\Wow6432Node\AppID\`
4. The new key should be called the same as the com object GUID.
5. Under the new key you just added, add a new REG_SZ (string) Value, and call it `DllSurrogate`. Leave the value empty.
6. Create a new Key under `HKey_Local_Machine\Software\Classes\AppID\` Again the new key should be called the same as the COM object’s GUID. No values are necessary to be added under this key.